# NSJSONSerialization not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, serialization

Im trying to parse a json string into a dictionary. For that im using the following code:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json_string];
```

This gives me the following error:

```
+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class...
```

I searched in Apples documentation and i saw that class is included in Foundation framework (i have that framework included in my project). I dont know why is this happening.

Any idea? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Which iOS version are you trying to run this on - it's only available in 5.0 and above.

Comment: My Apple documentation doesn't know this method either. It knows `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`...

Comment: you are passing json_string instead NSData object

Comment: As @Martin_R says you're passing a string and you're not giving it all the required arguments. __How did this even compile__?

Comment: @deanWombourne im using 6.1

Comment: @DipenPanchasara yes, i replaced and still the same error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot some arguments:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json_string options:0 error:&error];
```

And note that the first argument is a `NSData` object, not a string.

Comment: yes, thats it: i wasnt using the same method. When i can i accept this answer

Comment: @oPi: I think you have to wait some minutes (maybe 5, I don't know), then you can accept by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: A very minor suggested change: you may want to use `kNilOptions` instead of `0` for better readability and possible future-proofing, although this use of 0 is admittedly pretty unlikely to change.  (It's declared in MacTypes.h.)

Answer (score 4):

The full selector is `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`, so it looks like you are missing two arguments.  Try something similar to this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [rawJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Note that this takes in an `NSData` argument and not an `NSString` argument, and won't always return an `NSDictionary`, it could be an `NSArray` or another Foundation object.  In production use you should check the `error` argument before you trust that `jsonObject` is a valid object.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you first need to convert your string to an NSData object, and call the correct class method of NSJSONSerialization. You can do the following:

```
NSData *stringData=[json_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonError=nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary =[NSJSONSerialization  JSONObjectWithData:stringData options:0 &jsonError];
```

Check the jsonError for tips on what went wrong, if anything. If things went well, you will have your dictionary populated with the json_string information.